# angular.js html5mode page refresh issue

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, ngroute, html5mode

I converted my angular.js project to html5mode everything was working good until I tried to refresh my page. I did a little research and find out it is related to server-side.

I add `<base href="/index.html">` to my index.html in head before everything.

Then add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');` to my app config.

And as suggested in other questions I added these lines to my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

But my problem is continues.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
    RewriteRule (.*) /#!/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```